# changing font and text sizes in SVG files in a batch

Tags: svg

I have few hundert SVG files.

I am looking for a way to change font, text size and reset eventual transform matrix (so that the text is not distorted) in all of them so that the text is the same in all files.

Any ideas how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Here is the code for Matlab that changes the properties of svg objects.

```
% this script requires the following functions

% struct2xml
% https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28639-struct2xml

% xml2struct
% https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct


% read the file into structure

filename = 'car_on_a_road.svg';

XML = xml2struct(filename);

% the text and its params are stored in flowRoot
for i = 1:length(XML.svg.g.flowRoot)
    %     modify fonts
    if length(XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.flowPara) == 1
        if isfield(XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.flowPara.Attributes,'style')==1
        XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.flowPara.Attributes.style='font-size:16px';
        end
    end

    %     for 2 line text
    if length(XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.flowPara) == 2
        XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.flowPara{1}.Attributes.style='font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16px;line-height:100%;font-family:''Times New Roman'';-inkscape-font-specification:''Times New Roman, Italic'';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start';
        XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.flowPara{2}.Attributes.style='font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16px;line-height:100%;font-family:''Times New Roman'';-inkscape-font-specification:''Times New Roman, Italic'';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start';
    end

    if isfield(XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.Attributes,'style')==1
     XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.Attributes.style='font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16px;line-height:100%;font-family:''Times New Roman'';-inkscape-font-specification:''Times New Roman, Italic'';text-align:start;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none';   
    end



    % only do if "transform" field exists
    if isfield(XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.Attributes,'transform')==1
        % only do if "matrix" text exists in this field
        if contains(XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.Attributes.transform,'matrix')
            % read original text position
            parsed_matrix_data = regexp(XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.Attributes.transform,',','split');
            %       
            E = str2double(parsed_matrix_data{5});
            F = str2double(regexprep(parsed_matrix_data{6},'[)]',''));

            % reset transformation matrix to remove any stretching of the text
            XML.svg.g.flowRoot{i}.Attributes.transform = sprintf('translate(%f, %f )',E,F);
        end

    end

end

% save to file, to different dir
struct2xml( XML, strcat('modified\',filename) )
```